# Nginx Redirect from HTTP to HTTPS works in Firefox but not in Chrome

Tags: nginx, https, redirect, http, firefox

with my Nginx configuration (see below) redirecting from http to https works fine when accessing the page (http://example.com/) with Firefox. But for some strange reason it does *not* work with Chrome.

```
server {
    listen                    80;
    server_name               example.com;
    return                    301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen                    443 ssl;
    server_name               example.com;
    server_tokens             off;
    ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com_fullchain1.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/ssl/example.com_privkey1.pem;
    ssl_session_cache         builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols             TLSv1.3;
    ssl_ciphers               "HIGH !aNULL !eNULL !EXPORT !CAMELLIA !DES !MD5 !PSK !RC4";
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    access_log                /var/log/nginx/httpd-example.com.log;
}
```

Uuh, and when I look at the requests being send in the Dev Tools, it seems that Firefox (although I request http://example.com) just asks for https://example.com directly. Am I missing something?

Comment: did you checked the logs? please provide them from a typical request